# How to use crypto.createSign with a DiffieHellman private key in node.js?

Tags: node.js, cryptography, sign, diffie-hellman

I'm trying to use a DH private key to sign a message with the node crypto lib. I'm running into an error that I can't seem to fix :{

```
var crypto = require("crypto");

var bob = crypto.getDiffieHellman("modp17");

bob.generateKeys();

var sign = crypto.createSign("RSA-SHA256");

sign.write("hello world");

var message = sign.sign(bob.getPrivateKey());
```

Error

```
140735140705040:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
Error: SignFinal error
    at Sign.sign (crypto.js:398:27)
    at repl:1:18
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at repl.js:249:20
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:122:7)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
```

Comment: Did you get how to put the DH private key in PEM format, @naomik ?

Answer (score 2):

The private key you get from `getPrivateKey()` is not in PEM format, which is [what `sign()` is expecting](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/crypto.html#crypto_sign_sign_private_key_output_format).

Comment: How does one make this key PEM formatted? Is there a way to do it using the standard crypto library?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the private key in PEM format following the answer of @mscdex in this link:

[Unable to sign a file with nodejs crypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39696888/unable-to-sign-a-file-with-nodejs-crypto)

You will need the `asn1.js` and `bn.js` modules.

I hope this can help someone.