# Unable to sign a file with nodejs crypto

Tags: node.js, header, signature, private-key, elliptic-curve

I've created a private Key with nodejs crypto and want to sign a file with this key.
My code is following:

```
var ecdh = crypto.createECDH('brainpoolP512t1');
        ecdh.generateKeys();
        var key = ecdh.getPrivateKey('buffer');

        var data= fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
        var sign = crypto.createSign('sha512');
        sign.update(data);
        var signature = sign.sign(key, 'hex');
```

But I get the error:

```
Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
    at Error (native)
    at Sign.sign (crypto.js:283:26)
    at /....js:32:27
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/.../node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:52:37)
    at runCallback (timers.js:578:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:554:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:533:5)
```

I know it has something to do with the key format, but I don't know how to fix this. Can anyone help?

UPDATE: 
I edited the privateKey to fit the pem format:

```
var KEY_START = '-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----\n';
var KEY_END = '\n-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----';

const ecdh = crypto.createECDH('brainpoolP512t1');
            ecdh.generateKeys();
            var key =KEY_START + ecdh.getPrivateKey('base64') + KEY_END;        
            var data= fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
            const sign = crypto.createSign('sha512');
            sign.update(data);
            var signature = sign.sign(key, 'hex');
```

And now I geht a different error:

```
Error: error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long
    at Error (native)
    at Sign.sign (crypto.js:283:26)
    at /...js:37:27
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/.../node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:52:37)
    at runCallback (timers.js:578:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:554:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:533:5)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key you sign the data with needs to be a valid PEM-encoded private key. The DH `getPrivateKey()` function does not return a key in this format, it returns the bare private key data.

Your options include:

- Generating a private key via the OpenSSL key generator utility or similar
- Using third-party node modules to properly encode the private key as outlined in [RFC 5915](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5915). Full example using the `asn1.js` and `bn.js` modules:

  ```
    var crypto = require('crypto');

    var asn1 = require('asn1.js');
    var BN = require('bn.js');

    function toOIDArray(oid) {
      return oid.split('.').map(function(s) {
        return parseInt(s, 10)
      });
    }

    // Define ECPrivateKey from RFC 5915
    var ECPrivateKey = asn1.define('ECPrivateKey', function() {
      this.seq().obj(
        this.key('version').int(),
        this.key('privateKey').octstr(),
        this.key('parameters').explicit(0).objid().optional(),
        this.key('publicKey').explicit(1).bitstr().optional()
      );
    });

    // Generate the DH keys
    var ecdh = crypto.createECDH('brainpoolP512t1');
    ecdh.generateKeys();

    // Generate the PEM-encoded private key
    var pemKey = ECPrivateKey.encode({
      version: new BN(1),
      privateKey: ecdh.getPrivateKey(),
      // OID for brainpoolP512t1
      parameters: toOIDArray('1.3.36.3.3.2.8.1.1.14')
    }, 'pem', { label: 'EC PRIVATE KEY' });

    // Sign data
    var sign = crypto.createSign('sha512');
    sign.update('hello world');
    var signature = sign.sign(pemKey, 'hex');

    console.log('signature', signature);
  ```

Comment: I thought there should stand the file path of the file that i want to sign?

Comment: I've now also added a code example if you want to generate (within node) a valid PEM-formatted key from the DH private key.

Comment: Thank you very much! When trying your solution the error "TypeError: asn1.define is not a function" comes up.

Comment: Did you install the right module? It should be `asn1.js` and not `asn1`.

Comment: Installed asn1 instead of asn1.js, now it works fine. Thank you for your code! Spend a lot of time struggling with this.

Comment: How did you find the parameters for brainpoolP512t1? because I want to find it for P521 (aka secp521r1).

Comment: @Pablo Just search google for the algorithm's oid, it's typically one of the first few links in the search results. For example: http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.3.132.0.35

Comment: @mscdex can I perform encryption/decryption instead of signing/verifying?

Comment: @mscdex How do you convert the publicKey to pem using a similar technique?