# How to generate a PEM-formatted Key from a 64Byte raw hex-formatted Key

Tags: node.js, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption, pem

### I have the following problem:

After recreating the public key from a signed transaction, I try to encrypt some payload with it.
However the **node.js**-module named "**crypto**" is expecting a pem-formatted key in the **publicEncrypt(key, payload)** function.

### My Question:

How can I create the pem-formatted key from a raw hex-encoded key?

> Here is the recreated 64 Byte public key:
> 9f9f445051e788461952124dc08647035c0b31d51f6b4653485723f04c9837adb275d41731309f6125c14ea1546d86a27158eec4164c00bab4724eed925e9c60

### Information:

I know, that a pem-format-key consists of base64 encoded data, a header and a footer.

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
BASE64 ENCODED DATA
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I have also found out that within the base64 encoded data the following DER-structure is present:

```
RSAPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
    modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
    publicExponent    INTEGER   -- e
}
```

So the only question is **how** to get **from** the raw hex-encoded key **to** this DER-structure.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Are you sure that this is an RSA public key? It seems more logical that this is a secp256k1 public key, used in e.g. bitcoin, consisting of two 256 bit values indicating a point on a curve. Note that your value is not even odd, and since primes are odd, and since multiplying two odd values results in an odd value... well, it's odd that the modulus is not odd, is what I'm trying to say...

Comment: Thank you for your quick comment. Hmm you are right, it is a secp256k1 public key. I didn't really thought about that in the first place. I have both keys, public and private, which are secp256k1. But they can still be used to apply asymmetric encryption on a message, am I right? So the only problem is that I can't provide them as PEM format..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem solved

*Thanks to Maarten Bodewes and his comment regarding the key being secp256k1 and not RSA.*

After some further research, I finally managed to encrypt/decrypt a message asymmetrically with secp256k1 keys.
With the help of Cryptos **ECDH** class I managed to create a key-object and then assign the private key to it. When assigned, you can easily derive the public key with `getPublicKey()`. All participants would create a key object for themselves and assign their private keys to it. Then they share their retrieved public keys (in my case over a shared medium). In addition I used a npm-package named **standard-ecies** which provides the ECIES encryption-scheme.

**Code:**

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const ecies = require('standard-ecies');

var buffer = new Buffer("Hello World");

var ecdh = crypto.createECDH('secp256k1');
ecdh.setPrivateKey(privateKey);

var encryptedText = ecies.encrypt(ecdh.getPublicKey(), buffer);
var decryptedText = new Buffer(ecies.decrypt(ecdh, encryptedText));
```

I should have noticed this, because crypto's encryption function ([link to the api-doc](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_publicencrypt_key_buffer)) clearly works only with RSA keys and not with secp256k1 keys.
Anyway if someone has a similar issue, I hope this answer helps!

Comment: I've voted up, but please note that this doesn't really answer the question about converting an existing "flat" public key point to PEM. Unfortunately I don't know how to do this with JS (I've shown it for Java and other languages though). The trick is to convert to X9.62 or X.509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure for those wanting to look it up. Or simply finding the right API calls of course.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes check out this answer, it's for private key but maybe it can be used for public as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/61263419/1267201

Comment: @zavr Well, the ASN1 lib can certainly help, but the code will not be compatible.